# Newtonsoft JSON.NET 6.0.8 and Mono on Mac OSX fails in glorious manner

Tags: c#, mono, json.net

I've built a distributed systems application that makes heavy use of JSON.  The app runs great natively on Windows (tested on 7, 8, 8.1, Server 2008, Server 2012) and Ubuntu 14.04 with Mono

However, the app fails in a glorious manner when I attempt to run it on OSX Yosemite 10.10.2 (maybe others).  I've isolated some of the calls to Newtonsoft JSON.NET and run them in a standalone sandboxed app and can never reproduce the issue.  I've pasted the debug information below in hopes that someone sees something in the stack trace or otherwise that might point to an obvious problem.

```
Stacktrace:

  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) object.__icall_wrapper_mono_gc_alloc_vector (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper alloc) object.AllocVector (intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
  at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.AddRef (object) <0x00077>
  at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethodTokenGenerator.GetToken (System.Reflection.MemberInfo,bool) <0x0001b>
  at System.Reflection.Emit.ILGenerator.Emit (System.Reflection.Emit.OpCode,System.Type) <0x000ee>
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ILGeneratorExtensions.BoxIfNeeded (System.Reflection.Emit.ILGenerator,System.Type) <0x0007a>
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.DynamicReflectionDelegateFactory.GenerateCreateGetPropertyIL (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo,System.Reflection.Emit.ILGenerator) <0x0009b>
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.DynamicReflectionDelegateFactory.CreateGet<T> (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo) <0x000bf>
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ReflectionDelegateFactory.CreateGet<T> (System.Reflection.MemberInfo) <0x0007d>
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue (object) <0x0003f>
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter,object,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract&,object&) <0x000fe>
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter,object,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty) <0x00197>
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter,object,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract,Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty) <0x0015f>
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter,object,System.Type) <0x000bf>
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter,object,System.Type) <0x0053b>
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter,object,System.Type) <0x00019>
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObjectInternal (object,System.Type,Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer) <0x000e7>
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject (object,System.Type,Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting,Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings) <0x0003f>
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject (object,Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting,Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings) <0x00017>
  at kvpbase.kvpserver.serialize_json (object) <0x000e7>
  at kvpbase.kvpserver.obj_write (System.Net.HttpListenerContext,kvpbase.request_metadata,kvpbase.obj) <0x01bd7>
  at kvpbase.kvpserver.put_handler (System.Net.HttpListenerContext,kvpbase.request_metadata) <0x00f4f>
  at kvpbase.kvpserver.user_api (System.Net.HttpListenerContext,kvpbase.request_metadata) <0x0062f>
  at kvpbase.kvpserver.processor (System.Net.HttpListenerContext,kvpbase.http_request) <0x0103b>
  at kvpbase.kvpserver.conn_handler (System.IAsyncResult) <0x005a7>
  at System.Net.ListenerAsyncResult.InvokeCallback (object) <0x00051>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void__this___object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>

Native stacktrace:


Debug info from gdb:

(lldb) command source -s 0 '/tmp/mono-gdb-commands.1s6ayI'
Executing commands in '/private/tmp/mono-gdb-commands.1s6ayI'.
(lldb) process attach --pid 4136
Process 4136 stopped
Executable module set to "/usr/bin/mono".
Architecture set to: i386-apple-macosx.
(lldb) thread list
Process 4136 stopped
```

I removed a bunch of thread-related data for brevity.  The full text can be seen here: https://gist.github.com/jchristn/677c53abc3c3028d804f

The serialize_json method is as follows (quite simple):

```
public static string serialize_json(object obj)
{
  return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { });
}
```

And the Mono version:

```
sh-3.2# mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 3.10.0 ((detached/e204655 Mon Oct 13 08:50:28 EDT 2014)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           normal
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notification:  kqueue
    Architecture:  x86
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          yes(3.4svn-mono-(detached/e656cac)
    GC:            sgen
```

The JSON string in question looks like:

```
{
  "url": "http://localhost/root/home/foo",
  "user_guid": "root",
  "container_name": "home",
  "size": 3259,
  "num_objects": 1,
  "container_path": [],
  "child_containers": [
    "abcd",
    "foo",
    "large-dir"
  ],
  "obj_metadata": [
    {
      "key": "foo",
      "size": 3259,
      "created": "2014-10-24T07:44:24.5773422Z",
      "last_update": "2014-10-24T07:44:24.5773422Z",
      "last_access": "2014-10-24T07:44:24.5773422Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

And its definition:

```
public class dir_info
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string user_guid { get; set; }
    public string container_name { get; set; }
    public long size { get; set; }
    public int num_objects { get; set; }
    public List<string> container_path { get; set; }
    public List<string> child_containers { get; set; }
    public List<obj_info> obj_metadata { get; set; }
}
```

This is on an older Macbook Pro, but it has a Core 2 Duo and 8GB of RAM.  There is nothing else running on the machine.

Also tried updating Mono to 3.12.1 and it has the same issue.

```
sh-3.2# which mono
/usr/bin/mono
sh-3.2# mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 3.12.1 ((detached/b7764aa Fri Mar  6 15:32:47 EST 2015)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           normal
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notification:  kqueue
    Architecture:  x86
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          yes(3.6.0svn-mono-(detached/5486eb2)
    GC:            sgen
```

I've also tried running within Mono on Windows and the issue does not appear (v3.12.1).

Comment: I doubt anyone will be able to help you without seeing the json string that causes this exception.

Comment: Looks like an OutOfMemoryException. Rigth?

Comment: Updating with details now

Comment: dates, its always the dates. check what version of json you are using at both ends. I believe the latest version hasn't been ported to mono?

Comment: I'm using v6.0.0.0 of JSON.NET - should I go back to an earlier version?  Cheers

Comment: Correction, was using 6.0.8

Comment: Have you read [Mono throws OutOfMemoryException on Ubuntu but not OSX or Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27675175/mono-throws-outofmemoryexception-on-ubuntu-but-not-osx-or-windows) and [Segmentation fault using newtonsoft json in linux with mono](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646762/segmentation-fault-using-newtonsoft-json-in-linux-with-mono)?

Comment: Thanks for linking this, but the issue happens in OSX, not Ubuntu or Windows, and it's on an Intel x64 vs the issue in the link being with AMD.

Comment: AMD64 also known as x64. It's name of the 64-bit instruction set (architecture) which is used in Intel and AMD processors. Try to report about your problem to Xamarin.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  Nevertheless this is OSX and not Ubuntu having an issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with a simpler example? It would be really nice to have a short but complete example demonstrating the problem - the shorter the better...

Comment: Hi Jon, I wish I could :-/   "I've isolated some of the calls to Newtonsoft JSON.NET and run them in a standalone sandboxed app and can never reproduce the issue."  The application itself is quite small when compiled (250KB).  The serializer runs inside a thread that gets kicked off when an HTTP connection is received.  For what it's worth, sometimes this error is returned on the first connection request, and sometimes on a subsequent call (typically always before the third request).  Issue doesn't exist on Ubuntu or Windows so I'm hesitant to doubt the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had some similar strange experiences on iOS development. (Exceptions like this when using multitasking and JSON)
I have found adding these to mtouch AOT options resolved my problems:

nrgctx-trampolines=8096,nimt-trampolines=8096,ntrampolines=4048

Wish it can help you (and maybe other developers) too.

Comment: Oh.  My.  God.  I love you.  This has saved me.  For reference, I ran mono --aot=nrgctx-trampolines=8096,nimt-trampolines=8096,ntrampolines=4048 filename.exe, which runs the Ahead of Time compiler, and then I run my executable using mono filename.exe.  The problem is gone!  Thank you so much!!!